# How to create login form using felogin and how to logged in typo3 front end?

Tags: typo3-6.2.x

How to show login form in front end and after submit how to show logged user with logout link.

I have searched about login form but i could not get answer. I am using typo3 6.2.31.

Answer (score 0):

First: You should no longer use version 6.2 because the support for this version has expired since April 2017. So no more security updates will be delivered. An update to one of the LTS versions is associated with some effort, but usually easily possible.

Nevertheless, you can also use a login function under TYPO3 6.2. This is supplied as standard by TYPO3 System. Responsible for this is the extension felogin.

You can find everything you need at the following link:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/felogin/6.2/Index.html

If you need a frontend registration I can recommend the sf_register (https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/sf_register/).